# Did they eat Eddie?

Tags: rocky-horror-picture-show

When Dr Scott said "We're here to discuss Eddie " Frank says "That's a tender subject." But I'm not certain if Eddie was cooked and served or not.

Comment: It may help to be more explicit about which version of Rocky Horror you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

In all the versions of Rocky Horror that I've seen, Eddie is indeed the meat served at the dinner.  The original film is more explicit; Eddie has clearly been hacked up.

[image: dead eddie, as seen in the original filml]

Comment: Meatloaf for dinner again?